# How to find the parent of a short-lived process?

Tags: linux

Suppose there is a very short-lived process being repeatedly executed on a Linux system, its *effects* are visible (the computer beeps or whatever) but the process itself exits far too quickly to be caught by `ps` or `pstree` or otherwise examined – and it's not in the crontab or anything similar. How to find out what the process actually is, and what executes it?

(Can also apply to strange/malicious daemons with PPID of 1 that mysteriously get restarted by an unknown parent whenever killed.)

Answer (score 2):

Use **[forkstat](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/forkstat)** to monitor all process creations via the "netlink connector" subsystem.

```
# forkstat
Time     Event     PID Info   Duration Process
18:56:12 fork  1715703 parent          -bash
18:56:12 fork  1722638 child           -bash
18:56:12 exec  1722638                 ls -N -F -h --color=auto
18:56:13 exit  1722638      0   0.535s ls -N -F -h --color=auto
```

forkstat works on any Linux kernel, but it still relies on getting the command lines from `/proc/<PID>` separately from receiving the actual event, so there's still a chance for it to miss reading the full command line (though it *will* still report the event and PID in any case).

You could also try **[bpftrace](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace)** using eBPF tracepoints:

```
# cat > forkstat.bt <<EOF

#include <linux/sched.h> /* for curtask */

BEGIN {
        printf("%-8s %-16s => %-8s %s\n", "PPID", "COMM", "PID", "ARGS");
}

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exec* {
        printf("%-8d %-16s => %-8d ", curtask->parent->pid, comm, pid);
        join(args->argv);
}

EOF
```

```
# bpftrace forkstat.bt
Attaching 3 probes...
PPID     COMM             => PID      ARGS
1714659  bash             => 1723793  ls -N -F -h --color=auto
```

(Note that this bpftrace example needs *kernel headers* to be installed for the currently running kernel, e.g. the `linux-headers` package – similar to what you'd need when compiling modules.)

The **[fatrace](https://github.com/martinpitt/fatrace)** tool traces file access, not processes, but file access *does* include executing a program:

```
# fatrace -fO
bash(295866): RO /usr/bin/git
bash(295866): RO /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Again fatrace relies on /proc for obtaining the process names, so it may show `unknown` for processes that exit quickly, but that shouldn't cause problems as the *parent* is usually long-running and can be inspected.